# HTML form input to PHP array

Tags: php, html, forms

I need some help importing the user input from a form I created into a PHP array variable.

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
  <input type="text" name="input" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And the PHP variable:

```
$urls = array();
```

As so the end result after typing a list of links in the following format:

> 'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=30/03/1150005935/1&judet=30',
>   'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=30/03/1150005936/1&judet=30',
>   'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=30/03/1150005937/1&judet=30',

Would be:

```
$urls = array(
       'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=30/03/1150005868/1&judet=30',
       'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=30/03/1150005868/1&judet=30',
       'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=30/03/1150005868/1&judet=30',
);
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Use `explode` function:

```
$post = explode(',', $_POST['text']);
foreach($post as $link) {
    $urls[] = $link;
}

print_r($urls);
```

More info about the function here https://php.net/explode